# Why is my link not working for my html a tag even if the path is correct?

Tags: html

Can anyone tell me why my `href` isn't working here?

I've tried taking the `a` tag out of the `li` but didn't change anything. What am I missing?

```html
<ul class="social-media-list">
  <li>
    <a href="https://github.com/Coca95" target="_blank" class="contact-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The link doesn't have any pixels to click on. It has no content.

Comment: @Quentin I'm guessing that the OP has a fontawesome github icon in the link

Comment: @j08691 — Maybe, but they do need to provide a real [mcve].

Comment: Do you have Font Awesome imported in your `<head>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Just like Quentin said, there are no pixels to click on. Your code seems to have the icon which you want to click to get redirected to the URL in your `href`. I have imported font-awesome icons in `head` tag and now it works

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="social-media-list">
    <li>
      <a href="https://github.com/Coca95" target="_blank" class="contact-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: I have the font-awesome imported in my head.. tried with your link but didn't worked either.. 
What do you mean by "no pixels to click on"?

Comment: it meant that there was neither text nor icon to click on, but now i imported icons and there are pixels to click on

Comment: @Coca95 do you see the icon when u run it in your local host?

Comment: Yes I can see them and my cursor is a pointer for the link but nothing happen when I click on it